# How do I make JSHint complain about missing function parameters?

Tags: javascript, jshint, ecmascript-5

If I have a function:

```
export function createWeeklyStats(activities, offset, length) {
    ...        
}
```

And I call the function like:

`createWeeklyStats(myListOfActivities, 0)`

JSHint does not complain that I'm missing the `length` parameter. I could not find a matching enforcing option here:

[JSHint Options Reference](http://jshint.com/docs/options/)

Does one exist?

I'm updating an existing method to include a new required parameter, and while I'm a self-proclaimed adult, I'll throw a fit right here if my best way out is a full-text search.

Comment: Doesn't exist to my knowledge, probably because it's not easy to tell when a param would be optional and when not. So you could throw a fit... Or press `CTRL+SHIFT+F`?

Comment: What if I don't want any of them to be optional?

Comment: Definitely throw a fit.

Comment: jshint doesn't know how your code is executed, only how it it authored.

Comment: @dandavis But if it can determine that a variable is never used, surely it can determine that a function call is missing a parameter?

Comment: given that, there's still no way to require a param, so there's no way for hint to tell it's missing...

Comment: Fair enough - I guess I'm hitting a language barrier vs a JSHint barrier. I was just hoping that for *my* code only, I could stipulate that no arguments would be optional.

Comment: you would have to put in run-time checks inside the function in question for that capability.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, that's the same conclusion we're reaching here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977245/required-properties-constructor-args-in-ember-object-instances

Comment: If you consider that functions can be called using `.apply()` where the arguments are in a run-time built array, it is not possible to know at parse time what arguments will be in that array.  Only run-time argument checking can determine that.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm actually not familiar with `.apply()`, I'm new to JavaScript coming from a very statically-typed background, and just struggling to get over some of the "givens" that come with the language. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit of a mind challenging transition from a strongly typed language to a non-typed language.  You cannot use a compiler/parser to tell you about some types of coding mistakes.  What you need to get used to is doing more run-time argument checking, unit test everything and make sure to do end-to-end tests that exercise all code paths.  That is the only way to know that you didn't accidentally make a typing mistake that will kill the code at runtime.

Comment: I found it particularly a pain when you want to restructure/refactor some code and I was used to letting the C++ compiler tell me where all the changed references are.  With JS, you have to manually find them all and then make sure you test everything that calls it.  A good set of automated unit tests can help a lot.  And, JSHint does help - it just can't find everything.

Comment: compilers are a crutch for folks who can't write bug-free code...

Answer (score 1):

The commenters are correct that there is no way to ask js[hl]int to find this.

Here are some options:

#### Explicitly check arg count

Check argument count:

```
function createWeeklyStats(activities, offset, length) {
  assert(arguments.length === 3);
```

Granted, that will raise the error at run-time, rather than compile-time.

Perhaps you want to write a little higher-order function which helps you out here:

```
function check_arg_count(f) {
  return function() {
    assert(arguments.length === f.length);
    return f.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}
```

Now instead of calling `createWeeklyStats`, you call `check_arg_count(createWeeklyStats)`.

I don't see anything particularly wrong with this approach. It will be a little tricky dealing with optional arguments. At some point, you might want to throw in the towel and make the move to a more strongly typed language or TypeScript.

#### Use a refactoring tool

In this case you are refactoring, so how about using a refactoring tool? Many editors/IDE have such features. Check out the documentation.

There are other tools to help with refactoring. For instance, take a look at [grasp](https://github.com/gkz/grasp). Actually, the grasp tutorial describes a similar case involving refactoring a function's argument list:

```
$ grasp -r -e 'createWeeklyStats($a, $o)' -R 'createWeeklyStats($a, $o, 0)' })' .
```

This will add the third argument to all calls. Changing the new third parameter is something you will obviously have to take care of yourself. grasp provides other features to narrow the scope of the change.

#### Customize the linter

You can write custom rules for eslint (but apparently not jshint; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278003/extending-jshint-with-custom-checks)). This could get you started: https://gist.github.com/jareware/7179093. Also http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules.html.

Comment: TypeScript is another option.